# How can I Install pip3 with python on HDP3.0.1?

Tags: pip, sandbox, hdp

I've tried a few ways to install python3-pip on Hortonworks Sandbox HDP_3.0.1 but no success.

Could any one guide on how to achieve that correctly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's final answer for that:-

- Become a root user first

  `yum update`
- you may found yum update failed because of some unavailble package you may skip that with

  `yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<package_name>.skip_if_unavailable=true`
- remove installed python package which has no available pip

  `yum remove python36u`
- install new one which has pip3 package available with it

  `yum install python3`